# WhereDoesntHave Eloquent Query not working as intended in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query to return: All schedules that doesn't have program or all schedules that have at least a program but the program is yet to end.

The issue is that, the query returns all schedules that doesn't have a program and also all schedules that have a program where the program has ended.

Below is my code:

```
Schedule::where(['owner_id' => auth()->user()->owner->id,
            'session_id' => CurrentSession::fetchCurrentSession()->session_id
        ]) 
        ->whereDoesntHave('program', function(Builder $query){
            $query->where('end_date', null);
        })
        ->orderBy('schedule_time', 'asc')
        ->get();`
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `$query->whereNull('end_date');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a `Schedule` with no `program` relationship ***or*** a `Schedule` with a `program` that has a null `end_date` then you should specify that ***or*** in your query.

```php
Schedule::where([
        'owner_id' => auth()->user()->owner->id,
        'session_id' => CurrentSession::fetchCurrentSession()->session_id
    ])
    ->where(function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereDoesntHave('program')
            ->orWhereHas('program', fn (Builder $q) => $q->whereNull('end_date'));
    })
    ->orderBy('schedule_time', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no just simply use  `whereHas('program')` instead?